# Why OpenVPN not changing the ip address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn

I have created AWS client VPN and tried to connect with **OpenVPN**. By referring to different YouTube videos, after connecting using client the ip address is changing. In my case its not changing after my configurations.

The screenshot is the connection of my **AWS OpenVPN**:
[image: enter image description heres]

I am not sure that the steps iam followed is correct or not.

If you can share the steps/tutorial to set it up, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address of the client (or your laptop) doesn't change. But, additional IP address will be allocated from `Client CIDR range` which is specified at the time of [creating](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html#cvpn-getting-started-endpoint) the `Client VPN endpoint`.

You can verify the same by using the `ipconfig` command before/after establishing the VPN connection and the client (or your laptop) would be getting an additional IP address.

There are many articles in the internet around [vpn change ip address](https://www.google.com/search?q=vpn%20change%20ip%20address), but they don't change the laptop address, but mask your IP from the service provider.

Comment: thank you. What is the service provider that you mentioned , is it my internet provider ???

Comment: Google, Facebook etc

Comment: in command prompt it will show the changes. but how can i confirm that it is masked from service provider ?